# boto3 - aws sns - specify Sender ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

The following code works to send a message but when it arrives, it displays the text 'VERIFY' for a sender id. How do I specific a sender ID? I think it's done with the message attributes but I cannot figure out the syntax.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='Credentials',region_name='us-east-1')
theMessage='Now is the time for all good people to come to the aid of their party'
senderID='Godzilla'
snsclient = session.client('sns')
response = snsclient.publish(PhoneNumber='+84932575571', Message=theMessage)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
print(pp.pprint(response))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a third parameter MessageAttributes to the publish method.

```
snsclient.publish(PhoneNumber='+84932575571', Message=theMessage,MessageAttributes={
'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
  'DataType': 'String',
  'StringValue': 'Godzilla'   
}})
```

The sender id is not supported in many countries. see [AWS SNS SMS SenderId Supported Countries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html)

Comment: Thanks...it is not supported in either the USA or Vietnam.

Comment: Is there a full list of allowed message attributes documented somewhere? I can't seem to find it anywhere.